# Follow search result item with cross-site publishing

Tags: 2013, cross-site-publishing, follow

We have a site set up in SP 2013 with cross-site publishing. It is working well for the most part.

If a user searches on some term and a document comes up in the search results and they hover over it they get the hover panel. At the bottom of the panel there is a **Follow** link.

In other sites that don't use cross-site publishing, clicking the Follow link adds the document to the list of things I'm following. For example if I go to the authoring/catalog side and search for my document, I can follow it. Of course that only works for me because I am an admin and have access to the catalog/authoring side.

On the publishing side when I click the Follow link I get an error that Something went wrong and the details are

```
InvalidQueryString : Invalid query string.
```

All my searches come back with only information about setting up "cross site publishing." And if I don't include that I just get generic pages on how useful the Follow feature is.

Anybody run into this before or know where I can start looking to figure it out?

**EDIT**

This is the code that is on the Follow link. I assume the problem is that HP. Follow can't use a dynamically generated url like that?

```
href="javascript:HP.Follow('https://sp.example.org/services/nls/Pages/Details.aspx?NLSID=20', true, true)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The HP.Follow() function is actually only available while using HoverPanel (e.g. while working on Display Templates with the Callout Hover Panel), for which reason you cannot call it outside of this context. For any additional way to call Follow you would need to use the SocialManager and use the "Path" (while in a Display template) to retrieve the actual URL of the file.